# How to convert from `form_tag` to `simple_form_for` way for Sign In?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

This snippet works fine:

```
<%= form_tag(session_path) do |f| %>
   <p>
       <%= label_tag :email %>
       <%= email_field_tag :email, nil %>
    </p>
    <p>
       <%= label_tag :password %>
       <%= password_field_tag :password, nil %>
    </p>
        <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

But when I tried to refactor it to `simple_form_for` as per screenshot, it's giving me error ***Invalid email or password!***
[image]

```
# sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        if user = User.authenticate(params[:email],params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
            redirect_to user
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = 'Invalid email or password!'
            render :new
        end
    end
end
```

I'm feeling like there's something wrong in the line

```
<%= simple_form_for :session, url: session_path do |f| %>
```

In `routes.rb`: `resource :session` - Yes, it's singular, not plural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added `simple_form_for :session` the form started to send all parameters wrapped in the `session` key: `session: { email: 'email@email.com', password: 'password' }`. You'll see it if you check server log

Change in the controller:

```
User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
```